# How to understand partitions vs indexing in AWS Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, amazon-athena, partitioning

I have ~250 gzipped JSONL files (150mb each) sitting in an S3 bucket that i'm unnesting into a flattened table (Table 1). I'm then using CTAS to write the results into a table WITH format=Parquet (Table 2) so that I'm not unnesting at the query layer. My files in S3 are just subsets of a larger file, they aren't organized by date or anything similar.

Sample cols I'm importing :

- User ID (string)
- Department (string)
- Start Date (date)

Problem: I'm trying to partition the results so I can better query them, but my understanding of partitioning is that I can't partition columns that I'm loading into Table 1, because I'll get the "column repeated in partitioning columns" error, which I've been getting. During Table 1 creation, I can add partitions to unimported columns like Phone Number, Email, etc, but I don't think that helps me.

Questions:

- Am I confusing partitioning for indexing? Do I WANT to add partitions
  for my unimported columns so that my imported columns are slightly
  more grouped together?
- Should I be BUCKETING BY my imported columns? Tried that as well and
  had no success
- Is AWS Glue something I need here?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Partitioning in CTAS involves specifying the partition, often you will have to unpacking data first so the first table you created is must if you are working this way and not using spark for example.

Next up, Create a new table with Partition By clause on desired column. 
Selecting the Optimal partition column is important  <1000 distinct values and as much as even distribution as possible is also benificial for query performance.

So to your questions:
1. Paritioning is not indexing like in RDBMS
2. No need bucketing it will be hard to maintain
3. You can if you will use spark (IMO)

Comment: Got it I'm pretty sure I can do everything I need to do in Athena via DDL, I think I'm just having syntax issues.   If I'm trying to partition on the Department field, but also include the Department field as a queryable column, I keep getting the "column repeated in partitioning columns" error and this is my major hurdle.  How do you add a partition/index for a column you want to query against without that error presenting?

Comment: When you partition column you should NOT specified it in the columns list 
CREATE TABLE t1 (
 name string
 age int
country string
)
PARTITIONED BY (country string)
...

query the data:
SELECT country,name, age FROM impressions WHERE country = 'United States' ;